# Is the induced volume on submanifolds unique?

Tags: differential-geometry, volume, symplectic-geometry

consider a $2n$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ With a volume element $\omega$. Now consider a $(2n-2)$-dimensional submanifold $\mathcal{N}$.
How one can define a volume on $\mathcal{N}$ based on $\omega$. Is the induced volume unique?

Comment: In general a codimension $2$ submanifold of an orientable manifold need not be orientable. For example, if $K$ is a smoothly embedded Klein bottle inside $S^4$. For any manifold with a volume with a volume form, all volume forms are equivalent up to their total area by a fundamental theorem of Moser.